# A pythonic way to use Lxml to find all elements of a certain type

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm not very good with Lxml but thought a few of you might know how one can quickly get through the following task.  See below...  Specifically, I need to parse the XML to get the value of the name attribute in all of the category elements.  For example:

```
<categories>
  <category name="Test">
    <p>test_1</p>
  </category>
  <category name="Acme">
    <p>acme_1</p>
  </category>
</categories
```

So for the above case, the results would be the following category names as a result:

```
Test
Acme
```

Comment: What did you try? This is one of those places where showing your work, and what issues you had, would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [LXML tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) has a number of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = root_el.xpath('//category/@name')
```